use fzf for all readline / bash completions
Is it somehow possible to tweak readline in a way to always use an interactive fuzzy finder (fzf for example) for making the selection in bash completions?
I get from the gnu bash docs that readline is responsible for providing this behaviour, so I thought instead of configuring my own completions to use fzf it would be easier to tweak the general behaviour.
